# Efficient way to convert large multi-page TIFF to PDF

Tags: pdf, command-line, imagemagick, tiff, libtiff

I'd like to convert scanned multi-page TIFF files to PDF. The *convert* and *tiff2pdf* tools don't seem to work efficiently on large TIFFs. For a 80MB multi-page TIFF file *convert* quickly eats up all 16GB of memory on my PC and I killed *tiff2pdf* when the generated PDF reached 2GB in size. Yet *printing* the TIFF to PDF from Apples *Preview* program ran smoothly. Is there a Linux command-line way of doing this efficiently?